# Вешаем отображение форм на radio кнопки с помощью jquery

Tags: jquery

Всем привет.

есть блок с формами:

```
<div id="form-wrapper">
    <form id="form-1" method="POST" style="display:none"></form>
    <form id="form-2" method="POST" style="display:none"></form>
    <form id="form-3" method="POST" style="display:none"></form>
</div>
```

есть переключатели в виде radio кнопок:

```
<div id="step">
    <input type='radio' name='delivery' value='form-1' checked/>
    <input type='radio' name='delivery' value='form-2' />
    <input type='radio' name='delivery' value='form-3' />
</div>
```

названия форм соответствуют значениям радио кнопок

Как сделать так чтобы при переключении радио кнопки сменялась форма на нужную указанную в значении радио кнопки.

и соответственно(по умолчанию) радио кнопка с аттрибутом checked открывала соответствующую форму

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Ща сделаю..

Answer (score 3):

Это делается [вот таким](http://jsfiddle.net/4Pg6L/1/) способом.

```
<div id="form-wrapper">
    <form id="form-1" method="POST">
        <input value="form 1" /></form>
    <form id="form-2" method="POST"> 
        <input value="form 2" /> 
    </form>
    <form id="form-3" method="POST"> 
        <input value="form 3" /> 
    </form>
</div>
<div id="step">
    <input type='radio' name='delivery' value='form-1' checked />
    <input type='radio' name='delivery' value='form-2' />
    <input type='radio' name='delivery' value='form-3' />
</div>
```

-

```
#form-wrapper form {
    display: none;
}
```

-

```
$('#step input').click(function () {
    var elem = $('#form-wrapper');
    $('form', elem).hide();
    $('#' + this.value, elem).show();
});
$('#form-wrapper #' + $('#step input:checked').attr('value')).show();
```

Comment: @ХэшКод, простите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#step input").click(function(){ $("#"+$("#step input:checked").val()).show().siblings("form").hide() })
```

Основаная идея такова

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
<!--
    $("radio[name=delivery]").change(function(){
       var show = $(this).val();
       $("form").hide();
       $("#"+show).show("slow");
    });
   $("radio[name=delivery]").change();
 -->
</script>
```

Comment: Жесть, да и только.

Comment: В чем жесть?

Comment: Для чего `<!--`?

    $(this)val()

Точки не хватает. 

    $("form").hide();

Скроет все формы на сайте.

Comment: 1)Текст помещенный внутри комментарием  не парсится как XML (а значит валидный при доктайпе <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
) и воспринимается как обычная строка. Это позволяет всунуть внутрь тега что угодно (в том числе любой код) и при этом быть уверенным что парсер не упадет от невалидного XML.
2) ТОчку поправил спасибо
3)   `$("form").hide();`   - скроет  все, так и нужно, смотри следующую строку

Comment: 1. Что? Какой еще XML?

Comment: XML и XHTML

Comment: Начнем с того, что автор не просил писать валидный код.

Comment: 1) начнем с того, что валидный код надо писать по возможноси всегда
2) это всего лишь ответ на Ваш коммент

Answer (score 0):

Всем огромное спасибо!
На основе предложенных вариантов сколотил свой вариант...

```
var radio = $("input[name='delivery']:radio");
var radioCheckedDefault = radio.filter(":checked").val();
radio.change(function() {
    var elem = $('#form-wrapper');
    $('form', elem).hide();
    $('#' + this.value, elem).show();

});
$("#" + radioCheckedDefault).show().siblings("form").hide();
```

все работает, как надо.

Минимальная требуемая репутация - 15 (у вас 1), так что извиняйте, разживусь репутацией лайкну всем:)